# Mac OS X: running a service? (specifically apachectl in another location)

Tags: macos, services

I'm trying to run an alternate install of apache httpd (don't ask) on my Mac. I can do it but it only runs as long as I'm logged in, and I keep having to type

```
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
```

and was wondering if there was a way to setup a service on my Mac so I don't have to keep doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to use `launchd` the built in replacement for `cron`, `init` and `xinetd`. To do so you need to create an XML document (specifically a .plist) to define what you want to do. A program called [Lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/) provides an excellent GUI for doing this and the installation as well.

You can save the following file as `com.example.apache2.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.apache2</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/local/bin/apache2/bin/apachectl</string>
        <string>-k</string>
        <string>start</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You then want to install this .plist within `/Library/LaunchDaemons` because you want this to run when the computer starts up (as a service). You can do this by copying the file to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` (User Daemons in Lingon) and running the command `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LauchDaemons/com.example.apache2.plist`. Then whenever the computer is started up, the command is run. Of note, Launch Daemons in `/Library` are run as root so you don't need the sudo.

For more information on launchd, check out the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html), the [man page for launchd.plist](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html), [Getting Started with launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html), or you can search here on Super User as there are several questions already about launchd.

Comment: great! Thanks, there was actually a /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2.plist already there, so I looked at it and then ran that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be through launchd.

http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html

Comment: Why the downvote - this is the easiest method (albeit the question would be more helpful with actual instructions).

Comment: Because your solution is ridiculously convoluted, won't actually work and shouldn't be used by anyone.

Comment: @NSD: What is that in relation to? My question was in relation to a downvote on your answer.